# Changing images in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make the image change when clicking an li element, in the sense that it would move back up to the navigator bar and then move back down with another image as background! The thing is that with my code the image changes before it moves back up (so basically the image changes too early), and I'm not sure how to fix it...

Here is my jQuery

```
var click = false;

$("#1").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#1 span.indicator").css("color", "#ffa1d4");
});

$("#1").on("click",function(){
    if (click = false){
    var click = true;
    }
    else {
        var click = false;
        $("div.container").animate({height: '0%'});
        $("div.container").animate({width: '500px'});
    }
    $("div.container").css("background-color", "#faf4fc");
    $("div.container").css("background-image","url(images/1.jpg)");
    $("div.container").animate({height: '100%'});
    $("div.container").animate({width: '100%'});
    document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = "1";
});

$("#1").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#1 span.indicator").css("color", "#a187be");
});

$("#2").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#2 span.indicator").css("color", "#ffa1d4");
});

$("#2").on("click",function(){
    if (click = false){
    var click = true;
    }
    else {
        var click = false;
        $("div.container").animate({height: '0%'});
        $("div.container").animate({width: '500px'});
    }
    $("div.container").css("background-color", "#faf4fc");
    $("div.container").css("background-image","url(images/2.jpg)");
    $("div.container").animate({height: '100%'});
    $("div.container").animate({width: '100%'});
    document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = "2";
});

$("#2").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#2 span.indicator").css("color", "#a187be");
});
```

I hope that is a bit clear ;;

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gzx6g4sw/ Sorry this was bugging me. You don't need jquery to do hover effects.

Comment: Haha I know don't worry! It's like that because this is a part of a school assignment and it had to stay this way simply because our teacher demanded it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

animate has a callback function I think you need to use that

here is a demo https://jsfiddle.net/6fhzqr40/

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $("div").animate({height: '0', width: '0'},2000 , 
                     function(){
                        andimatetwo();

                     });

});

function andimatetwo(){
         $("div").css('background-color', 'green');
        $("div").animate({height: '500', width: '500'},2000 , 
                     function(){


                     });

}
```